# Variable in OLS regression becomes significant when accounting for covariate; is the predictor correlated more with the covariate than the DV?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I am running some exploratory tests on a dataset and have a conceptual question as I start to dive in. One of the strongest predictors of the DV (which is interest) was level of education, a dummy variable. OLS single regression results below.

```
    Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6304 -0.6304  0.3333  0.3696  2.0435 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.00000    0.26320  11.398   <2e-16 ***
Education3  -0.33333    0.31875  -1.046   0.2978    
Education4   0.30000    0.40775   0.736   0.4633    
Education5   0.63043    0.30059   2.097   0.0381 *  
Education6  -0.04348    0.33383  -0.130   0.8966    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9848 on 118 degrees of freedom
  (25 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1422,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1131 
F-statistic: 4.891 on 4 and 118 DF,  p-value: 0.001101
```

I was particularly interested in the relationship between Hispanic ethnicity and the DV. Here is the single regression output.

```
    Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.39024 -0.39024 -0.06098  0.93902  1.93902 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.0610     0.1147  26.695   <2e-16 ***
Hispanic      0.3293     0.1986   1.658   0.0999 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.038 on 121 degrees of freedom
  (25 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.02221,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01413 
F-statistic: 2.749 on 1 and 121 DF,  p-value: 0.09992
```

When I regress the DV on both variables, Hispanic becomes significant and its beta increases. However, I do not know how to characterize this change.

```
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.98472 -0.50539  0.07769  0.55702  1.84380 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.8973     0.2604  11.127   <2e-16 ***
Education3   -0.4543     0.3151  -1.442   0.1521    
Education4    0.2589     0.3989   0.649   0.5175    
Education5    0.6081     0.2939   2.069   0.0408 *  
Education6   -0.1283     0.3280  -0.391   0.6963    
Hispanic      0.4793     0.1878   2.552   0.0120 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9626 on 117 degrees of freedom
  (25 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1875,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1527 
F-statistic: 5.399 on 5 and 117 DF,  p-value: 0.000167
```

Could Hispanic ethnicity be a confounder of the relationship between education and interest? The dummy variables are tripping me up. An ANOVA indicated no relationship between education and Hispanic ethnicity and education does not seem to become insignificant when Hispanic is accounted for, so I assume not. However, if Hispanic ethnicity is a suppressor variable, why did the beta for the significant level of education decrease along with its error from the single predictor model? I would like to be elucidated on the mathematical relationships with the predictors here so I can better understand what to look for later on in my analysis. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: As an aside, presumably "education" goes from 1 to 6, but you have 4 dummy variables instead of 5 (which is what I would expect).   Also, while they aren't much known, there are methods for dealing with ordinal independent variables. One is optimal scaling. You might consider that. Finally, I think you should look at the interaction between your two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation of the predictor with another covariate indeed is a likely explanation of the phenomenon.

I will work out a (hopefully) more transparent example to highlight the issue.

Essentially, it illustrates that the short regression could be misspecified and that that leads to the coefficient on Hispanic mopping up both the effects of education and being hispanic, but that these turn out to offset each other so as to produce an overall zero (or at least insignificant) effect, even if both Hispanic and education do have their own effect.

From, e.g., https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/6-1-omitted-variable-bias.html we know that the OLS estimator of the "short" simple OLS regression (i.e., with controls omitted) of $y$ on $X$ (and a constant) only tends to
$$
\text{plim}\,\hat\beta_{1,s}=\beta_1+\rho_{X,u}\frac{\sigma_u}{\sigma_X},
$$
where $u$ is the error term of that short regression, $\rho_{X,u}$ denotes the correlation of $X$ and $u$ and $\sigma$ standard deviations.

Consider a true model
$$
y=X\beta_1+Z\beta_2+v
$$
Then, regressing on $X$ only implies
$$
u\equiv Z\beta_2+v.
$$
So if
$$\beta_1=-\rho_{X,u}\frac{\sigma_u}{\sigma_X}$$
the short regression will plim to 0, and will hence also often produce insignificant estimates, while the long (and "correct") regression will have the coefficient on $X$ tend to $\beta_1$, which, if nonzero, will also give significant t-statistics.

Here is an example with $\sigma_X=\sigma_Z=Var(v)=\beta_2=1$, $$E(X)=E(Z)=E(v)=Cov(X,v)=Cov(Z,v)=0,$$ $E(XZ)=-0.5$ and $\beta_1=0.5$, so that
$$
Var(u)=\beta_2^2Var(Z)+Var(v)=2
$$
and
$$
Cov(X,u)=E(XZ)\beta_2+E(Xv)=-0.5
$$
and thus
$$
\rho_{X,u}=\frac{Cov(X,u)}{\sigma_u\sigma_X}=-\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1}}
$$
Hence,
$$
\text{plim}\,\hat\beta_{1,s}=\beta_1+\rho_{X,u}\frac{\sigma_u}{\sigma_X}=\beta_1-\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}=\beta_1-0.5=0
$$

Here is a numerical example with relevant parts of the `summary.lm` output.

```
library(mvtnorm)
n <- 100

r <- -0.5
VarCovMat <- matrix(c(1, r, r, 1), ncol=2)
X <- rmvnorm(n, sigma=VarCovMat)

Var.v <- 1
v <- rnorm(n, sd=sqrt(Var.v))

beta.2 <- 1
beta <- c(0.5, beta.2)

y <- X%*%beta + v

> summary(lm(y~X[,1]))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X[, 1])

  
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.26474    0.13633   1.942    0.055 .
X[, 1]      -0.03298    0.14583  -0.226    0.822  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1



> summary(lm(y~X))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)


Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.1246     0.1066   1.169    0.245    
X1            0.5616     0.1338   4.199 5.96e-05 ***
X2            1.0632     0.1293   8.222 9.06e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```